# Water-Bucket problem

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge

This challenge is to calculate how to measure 4 liters of water with just two unevenly sized buckets, one of 3 liters and another of 5 liters, in minimum number of steps. To extend and generalize this, write a program to evaluate the minimum number of steps to measure “X” liters of water, with “Y” buckets each having a separate denomination.

Assumptions:

1. Each bucket used for measuring water should be unique in denomination and the number of buckets will be <= 3
2. The target amount to be reached has to finally reside in a single bucket (at the end of the measuring activity).
3. The bucket capacities and target amount will be <= 99
4. If there are multiple ways to measure the same amount, only one single way, having the minimum number of steps is required.
5. Ties will be broken by the smallest program.

**Examples:**

> 2,3,5,4
>   Implies that there are 2 buckets of capacity 3 and 5 each and the target amount desired is 4.
>
> 3,4,6,9,7
>   Implies that there are 3 buckets of capacity 4, 6 and 9 each and the target amount desired is 7.

**Answers:**

> 2,3,5,4
>   Fill 5
>   Move 5 to 3
>   Empty 3
>   Move 5 to 3
>   Fill 5
>   Move 5 to 3
>
> 3,4,6,9,7
>   Fill 4
>   Move 4 to 6
>   Fill 9
>   Move 9 to 6

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! Could you stop posting willy-nilly and spend a little time fixing the challenges you have already posted, please. As PhiNotPi said in a comment to your first post these are not up to spec. They do not specify a winning condition, and are difficult to read. Take some time to look at previous, [well received challenges](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), and consider using [the meta sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/423/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-iii) (a place to get suggestions before posting) in the future.

Comment: This has such promise...it would be a shame if it was abandoned in this state.

Comment: I agree with @dmckee. This could actually be a pretty fun challenge if it were better specified.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 363 chars

Golfed it, not sure if it is golf or not.  The map `P` maps a reachable state to the instructions used to get to that state.  Keeps enumerating reachable states until it finds one with the target amount of water in it.

```
I=input()
B=I[1:-1]
R=range(I[0])
P={(0,)*I[0]:""}
while P:
 Q={}
 for s in P:
  if I[-1]in s:print P[s];P=Q={};break
  for i in R:
   Q[s[:i]+(0,)+s[i+1:]]=P[s]+"Empty %d "%B[i];Q[s[:i]+(B[i],)+s[i+1:]]=P[s]+"Fill %d "%B[i]
   for d in R:m=min(s[i],B[d]-s[d]);Q[tuple(s[j]-[0,m][j==i]+[0,m][j==d]for j in R)]=P[s]+"Move %d to\
 %d "%(B[i],B[d])
 Q.update(P);P=Q
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Ruby

The following code gives a ruby implementation of the task described above. The specification is as follows:

**Input:** A list of integers on STDIN, where the first one is the number *n* of buckets available, followed by *n* distinct bucket denominations, followed by the target amount of water.

**Output:** A list of operations needed to reach the target amount in any bucket or a corresponding message if that is not possible.

**Task:** Start with *n* empty buckets each of different integer denomination. In each step you can do one of the following:

- *Fill X*: fills the bucket with denomination *X* with water such that it contains exactly *X* water
- *Empty Y*: empty the bucket with denomination *Y*, i.e. no water inside after this operation
- *Move A to B*: take any water in bucket with denomination *A* and put it into bucket with denomination *B* up to the point where bucket *B* is full. (Example: Bucket 5 has 4 liters in it and bucket 3 has 2. Then Move 5 to 3 will transfer 1 liter leaving bucket 5 with 3 liters while bucket 3 is full afterwards.)

The algorithm used is quite straightforward. On a list of bucket configurations (i.e. a list of buckets with their corresponding fill levels) perform all possible operations. Each one will lead to a new configuration. Keep those which you didn't had already in previous steps (i.e. those that are really novel). This way we get a list of configurations reachable be 1 step, 2 steps, ... . Whenever we reach a configuration where one bucket is filled with exactly the target amount we are done.

Since we have a constructive algorithm, i.e. we know in each step which operation we perform, we can simultaneously build the list of operations in textual representation for any bucket configuration.

Example: 3 buckets with denominations 7, 9 and 11. Target amount of water is 1.

**Input:**

```
3, 7, 9, 11, 1
```

**Output:**

```
Solution found with 7 steps:
 Fill 7 Move 7 to 11 Fill 7 Move 7 to 11 Move 7 to 9 Fill 7 Move 7 to 9
```

**Code:**

```rb
# get input as list of integers
input = gets.split(/,/).map{|s| s.to_i}

count = input.shift
start = (1..count).map{[input.shift, 0]}
target = input.shift

# a bucket configuration is a list of buckets, each represented as
# array [denomination, fill level], i.e. initial configurations
# is e.g. [[3, 0], [5, 0]] for empty buckets of size 3 and 5

configurations = {start => ""}
step = 0
solution = nil

current = configurations.keys

while current.size > 0 do

  # debug output (each configuration rechable within step)
  puts "- #{step} ------------------------------------------"
  current.each{|k| puts "#{k.to_s} #{configurations[k]}"}
  puts

  # test current configurations if target amount is included
  solution = current.select{|k| k.any?{|b| b[1] == target}}[0]  
  break if solution

  step += 1
  new_configurations = {}
  
  # for all configurations for all buckets
  current.each{|k|
    k.size.times{|i|

      # do a fill operation on this bucket
      kn = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(k))   # make deep copy
      # increase fill level to bucket denomination
      kn[i][1] = kn[i][0]
      new_configurations[kn] = "#{configurations[k]} Fill #{kn[i][0]}"

      # do an empty operation on this bucket
      kn = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(k))   # make deep copy
      # set fill level to zero
      kn[i][1] = 0
      new_configurations[kn] = "#{configurations[k]} Empty #{kn[i][0]}"

      # do a move operation on any other bucket
      k.size.times{|j|
        kn = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(k))   # make deep copy
        # amount movable is current amount or space left in other bucket
        h = [kn[i][1], kn[j][0]-kn[j][1]].min   
        kn[i][1] -= h
        kn[j][1] += h
        new_configurations[kn] = "#{configurations[k]} Move #{kn[i][0]} to #{kn[j][0]}"
      }
    }
  }

  # remove any configuration already reachable with less steps
  new_configurations.keep_if{|conf| !configurations[conf]}

  # merge new configurations
  configurations.merge!(new_configurations)

  current = new_configurations.keys

end

if solution
  puts "Solution found with #{step} steps:"
  puts configurations[solution]
else
  puts "Impossible to reach target"
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the OP hasn't made the input specification mandatory. if you use space separated values, you can use `gets.split`